# Why is this PHP switch acting up

Tags: php, html, switch-statement

I'm working on this assignment where we need to create a little web app to have someone order what they want on a sandwich, and then put it in simpler terms for whoever gets the order to make the sandwich.

I've asked a couple questions about this already, but I hit one final roadblock, have been trouble shooting it for an hour, and can't figure out what's wrong. Everything works if I just comment out the cheesetype switch in the PHP, but as soon as I reintroduce it, I get a server error. I more than triple checked all the syntax, but as soon as that switch shows up things get wonky. What did I do wrong?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sandwich Order</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="sandwichform" method="post" action="sandwichmaker.php">
Size
<select name="size">
    <option value="small">Small</option>
    <option value="medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="large">Large</option>
</select><br/>
Meat Type
<select name="meattype">
    <option value="ham">Ham</option>
    <option value="turkey">Turkey</option>
    <option value="beef">Roast Beef</option>
    <option value="salami">Salami</option>
</select><br/>
Cheese
<select name="cheesetype">
    <option value="american">American</option>
    <option value="swiss">Swiss</option>
    <option value="jack">Monterey Jack</option>
</select><br/>
Bread Type
<select name="breadtype">
    <option value="white">White</option>
    <option value="wheat">Wheat</option>
</select><br/>
Condiments<br/>
Ketchup<input type="checkbox" name="condiments[]" value="ketchup"><br>
Mustard<input type="checkbox" name="condiments[]" value="mustard"><br>
Mayonnaise<input type="checkbox" name="condiments[]" value="mayo"><br>
BBQ Sauce<input type="checkbox" name="condiments[]" value="bbq"><br>
<b>Extras:</b><br/>
Tomato<input type="checkbox" name="extras[]" value="tomato"><br>
Lettuce<input type="checkbox" name="extras[]" value="lettuce"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php

$breadtype=$_POST['breadtype'];
$size=$_POST['size'];
$meattype=$_POST['meattype'];
$cheesetype=$_POST['cheesetype'];
$condiments=$_POST['condiments'];
$extras=$_POST['extras'];

if ($breadtype == "white")
{
    $breadimage="images/whitebread.jpg";
}
elseif ($breadtype == "wheat")
{
    $breadimage="images/wheatbread.jpg";
}

$breadoutput="<img src=\"$breadimage\" />";

switch ($size) {
case "small":
    $slices=2;
    break;
case "medium":
    $slices=4;
    break;
case "large":
    $slices=6;
    break;
}

$sizeoutput=$slices ." slices of";

switch ($meattype) {
case "ham":
    $meatimage="images/ham.jpg";
    break;
case "turkey":
    $meatimage="images/turkey.jpg";
    break;
case "beef":
    $meatimage="images/turkey.jpg";
    break;
case "salami":
    $meatimage="images/salami.jpg";
    break;
}

$meatoutput="<img src=\"$meatimage\" />";

$switch ($cheesetype) {
case "american":
    $cheeseimage="images/american.jpg";
    break;
case "swiss":
    $cheeseimage="images/swiss.jpg";
    break;
case "jack":
    $cheeseimage="images/jack.jpg";
    break;
}

$cheeseoutput="<img src=\"$cheeseimage\" />";

foreach ($extras as $extra)
{
    $ei="images/" .$extra .".jpg";

    $extrasimage .= "<br/><img src=\"$ei\"/>";
}

$extrasoutput="and " .$extrasimage;

foreach ($condiments as $condiment)
{
    $ci="images/" .$condiment .".jpg";

    $condimentsimage .= "<br/><img src=\"$ci\"/>";
}

$condimentsoutput="and " .$condimentsimage;

echo $breadoutput;
echo "<br>";
echo $sizeoutput;
echo "<br>";
echo $meatoutput;
echo "<br>";
echo $cheeseoutput;
echo "<br>";
echo $extrasoutput;
echo "<br>";
echo $condimentsoutput;
?>
```

Comment: What is wrong? "server error" - what server error?

Comment: Its `switch` not `$switch`

Comment: You have `$switch ($cheesetype)` - you need to remove that initial `$`

Comment: Do your error logs show anything?

Comment: *Chuckle* Someones in college! :-)

Comment: Look to your server logs: what is the error message?

Comment: +1 for the cool assignment- when I learnt programming, we were all about creating fictionary banks for you to credit/deposit $$$.

Comment: I don't have access to the server. It's a dev one for my class. And yes, I am in college! Pretty fun course so far.

Comment: If you run this on your own computer, you'll have access to the logs. Have you a web server installed on your own machine?

Comment: Valid. Wasn't even thinking about WAMP. In Chrome though, I'm getting the idea that server error means syntax error.

Comment: I noticed that when I typed $switch ($something) {}, my IDE catches it as an error. You should consider using Netbeans or Eclipse or another IDE to catch these types of errors for you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$switch ($cheesetype) {
```

should be

```
switch ($cheesetype) {
```

Drop the `$` sign.

Comment: Wowwww. Hour wasted. Thank you so much.

Comment: I once spent 3 hours + 1 hour drive to uni for my tutor to tell me that i had an extra `;` at the end of a statement. Easiest of mistakes can easily slip through to the keeper.

Comment: Using a good IDE would keep you safe from this type of mistakes. I personally use Aptana Studio.

Answer (score 0):

it should be switch not $switch